# Skip read with implied do-loops in Fortran without dummy variable

Tags: fortran, readfile

I would like to skip `n` number of lines. It could be done as:

```
do i = i,n
  read(file,*)
enddo
```

However, I would like to do that by implied do-loop without dummy variable, like

```
read(file,*)(,i=1,n)
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that, but I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: yeah, it seems to be not possible. I just want to save some code lines.

Comment: I can do that if this is the only way out.

Comment: Save some code lines? You know it's 2013 and not the 1960's? Computers have >GB of storage and you're worried about the difference of a few bytes?

Comment: when I meant save code lines, I did not mean file size but making it more readable and fancier. Implied-do would approach my purpose, and then I got curious whether it is possible or there is another solution

Comment: I would argue that implied do loops make a code *less* readable, most especially if you could write it without an argument.

Comment: I agree it may be less readable, but not in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
READ (file, '(' // REPEAT('/',n-1) // ')')
```

but promise you won't do this...

Comment: Interesting. I stand corrected on my comment that it can't be done.